# ycbcr color range

Tags: c#, aforge

I'm trying to detect skin color using Aforge.Net.
I found some values for skin color, but they are integers values

> Y is in [0,255]
>  Cb is in [80,135]
>  Cr is in [131,185]
>  I
>   just need to convert them to the ranges in the Aforge.Net, where 
>   Y is in [0,1], 
>  Cb is in [-0.5,0.5], 
>  and Cr is in
>   [-0.5,0.5].

So how can I convert the ranges to these ranges?

Comment: Divide by 255.0 and subtract 0.5 from Cb and Cr.

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked!
If I want to convert to HSV ranges in Afroge.net, where
H is in [0,359]
S is in [0,1]
V is in [0,1] 
What should I do?